# conditional constraint: if $x \in [a,b] => z=1$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have an optimization problem in which a constraint should hold if the variable $x$ is inside the interval $[a,b]$. I assume you can model it by introducing a binary variable $z$ with $z=1$ if $x \in [a,b]$.
So I would like to have something like

$$
x \in [a,b] \Rightarrow z=1
$$

Is there a way to model this with linear constraints or how would you model this in general?

Answer (score 2):

The condition $$x \in [a,b] \Rightarrow z=1$$ 
can be reformulated as:
$$z=0 \Rightarrow x<a \text{ or } x>b$$
This can be linearized using standard tools:
$$\begin{align}
& x \le a - 0.001 + M\delta + Mz\\
& x \ge b + 0.001 - M(1-\delta) - Mz\\
&\delta \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$$