# Indicator Variable if x is in specific range

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, mixed-integer-programming

I have a modelling question. I want to model that if my varibale $x$ is in the interval $[a,b]$, where $a,b >0$, my indicator variable $X \in \{0,1\}$ should be 1 (if $x$ is not in $[a,b]$, the indicator variable can attain any value).
I'm sure that this kind of problem is quite common in practice, but I couldn't really find anything.

What would be the best way to model this? I guess there are several formulations which model this constraint. Which would be the best regarding computation times? Do you know some papers/publications which cover this topic?

Best regards,
ops

Answer (score 1):

The implication 
$$ x\in[a,b] \Rightarrow y=1 $$
can be stated as
$$ y=0 \Rightarrow x<a \text{ or } x >b$$

Traditionally we would formulate this as:
$$\begin{align}
&x \le a - 0.001 + M\delta + My\\
&x \ge b + 0.001 - M(1-\delta) -My\\
&\delta \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$

where $M$ is a large enough constant. This was already answered (but not accepted) here [conditional constraint: if $x \in [a,b] => z=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492386/conditional-constraint-if-x-in-a-b-z-1).

Advanced solvers may support indicator constraints, SOS1 variables or even an **or** functionality directly.

A version without big-$M$'s but with indicator constraints and SOS1 variables can look like:

$$\begin{align}
&y=0 \Rightarrow x \le a - 0.001 + s_1\\
&y=0 \Rightarrow x \ge b + 0.001 - s_2 \\
& s_1, s_2 \ge 0\\
& \text{SOS}1(s_1,s_2)
\end{align}$$

The SOS1 set will make sure that only one of  the slack variables $s_1, s_2$ will be non-zero. In other words,

$$ s_1 \cdot s_2 = 0$$

Note that I typically drop these $0.001$ terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first formualtion I do understand, but I have problems with the second formulation. I looked up SOS1 and as far as I know it means that either s1 or s2 can be 1 and the other must be 0. But I still have some difficulties to see how those constraints work.

Comment: That looks like a documentation bug. The correct definition of a sos1 set is that only one member can be non-zero.