# Question to the solution of "Indicator Variable if x is in specific range"

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

This question is to query the solution provided by [Erwin Kalvelagen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/295867/erwin-kalvelagen) to the post

> [Indicator Variable if x is in specific range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571788/indicator-variable-if-x-is-in-specific-range?newreg=eb22a604db1a4ce79cd05fe14fbe4640)

and

> [conditional constraint: if $x \in [a,b]=> z=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492386/conditional-constraint-if-x-in-a-b-z-1)

(Sorry for not adding comments under the original posts since I don't have enough reputations to do so ...)

In [Erwin Kalvelagen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/295867/erwin-kalvelagen)'s solution, we can observe that $z = 0$ does guarantee that either $x<a$ or $x>b$. However, it does not guarantee that $z = 1$ leads to $x \in [a, b]$.

For example, considering when $x<a$, $z=1$, $\delta = 1$, the first inequality is $$x \leq a - 0.001 + M + M $$ which is correct.

The second inequality :
$$
x \geq b + 0.001 - 0 - M
$$

which is also correct (since $b - M$ is a very big negative number)

However, now the $x$ does NOT belong to the interval $[a, b]$, hence $z = 1$ is NOT an indicator to its belongingness.

Could someone help to address it? 
Or let me know where I am wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to *additionally* want $z=1 \Rightarrow x \in [a,b]$. This can be linearized as:
$$\begin{align}
& x \ge a - M(1-z)\\
& x \le b + M(1-z)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, if we want to have double-binding between $z = 1$ and $x \in [a, b]$. Then we need to have all 4 inequalities: $$x<a + M \delta + M z$$ $$x> b - M (1 - \delta) - M z$$ $$x > a - M (1 - z)$$ $$x < b + M (1- z)$$. Right?

Comment: @YuWang that's right. Note that you need non-strict inequalities in linear optimization.